# How to create multiple PDF file in OpenACS

Tags: pdf-generation, tcl, openacs

Currently I can generate a single PDF file using this process:

1. `ad_returnredirect` to ADP pages (the PDF template)
2. Create a PDF using the `eval [template::adp_compile -file $template]`.
3. `ad_returnredirect "/pdfs/$folder/${fileprepend}.pdf"` to file location to download.

But what I need is to generate a multiple PDF files. I tried to use the same process and add a loop... but as you can see it requires to visit the ADP pages first before it can generate template and create a PDF files, is there any other way to create a PDF files in sub-process without visiting the pages for template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP file delivery only allows one file to be returned, and there is no way to package multiple PDF files in one return. So I understand it's HTTP and not OpenACS that causes your "problem".

I'd just setup one page with links to all the PDF document you'd want the user to download. Or you could zip them together into one file.